# Validation on View Model using Model

Tags: validation, model-view-controller, devexpress

I have **ViewModels** and **Models**.
ViewModels use Models.
I have 1 ViewModel for 1 Controller.

ex:

```
public class ReferentielFournisseursViewModel
{       
    public Fournisseur monFournisseur { get; set; }
    [...]
    public Adresses ListeSites { get; set; }
}

public class Fournisseur
{
    public int NoFournisseur { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Sigle { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Siren { get; set; }
}
```

In this case, I use validation by annotation: "Required" on the model.
But I have to create an other page using the same model without this validation.

```
public class DemandeDePrixViewModel
{
    public Fournisseur monFournisseur { get; set; }
    [...]
    public Commande CommandeEnCours { get; set; }
}
```

How I can use Validation on the ViewModel instead of the Model ?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the IValidateableObject interface:

```
public class Model: IValidatableObject
{
   public int Property { get; set; }

   public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
   {
      var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
      if (Property < 5)
      {
          results.Add(new ValidationResult("Prop1 must be larger than 5"));
      }
      return results;
  }
}
```

This code will automatically run when ModelState.IsValid is called

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject?view=netcore-3.1